# Má tradução quando tenta marcar mais de um @user

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Ao tentar adicionar um comentário com dois usuários marcados recebi a mensagem abaixo e fui impedido de publicar:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Quando na verdade, acredito eu, que eu posso marcar `apenas um` e não mais que isso.

Comment: Já exite um post sobre isso [Aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75)

Comment: @bfavaretto mal minha.. Quer que eu exclua ou espera fechar? Já dei meu voto até.

Comment: Deixa fechar. O seu screenshot é legal.